# How to group by and summarise values in a numeric vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
data_frame <-
  tribble(
    ~a,    ~b,
    "1",   27,              
    "1",   29,
    "2",   33,
    "2",   37
  )
```

I want to group this data frame by the variable `a`, and summarise all the values of `b` in a numeric vector.

However, I have only figured out how to summarise the values of `b` in a character vector, as displayed by the following code:

```
data_frame %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  summarise(values = paste(b, collapse = ","))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   a     values
#>   <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 1     27,29 
#> 2 2     33,37
```

How can I summarise the values in `b` so that I end up with summarising the values in b in a numerical vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want to store data in a list which will keep data as numeric.

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(b = list(b))

#    a     b        
#  <chr> <list>   
#1 1     <dbl [2]>
#2 2     <dbl [2]>
```

This can also be done in base R :

```
aggregate(b~a, data_frame, list)
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data_frame)[, .(b = list(b)), a]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data_frame)[, .(b = .(b)), a]
#   a     b
#1: 1 27,29
#2: 2 33,37
```